# laravel datatable relationships

Tags: datatable, laravel-4.2

So in this app `Drawing` `belongsTo` `Customer`. I have datatable

```
            <table id='drawing-table' class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Drawing number</th>
                        <th>Customer</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

which indicates `$darwing->number` and `$customer->title`. To load info I `use yajra\Datatables\Datatables;`.

Data  is loaded with this JS method:

```
$(function () {
    $('#drawing-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{{route('drawings.datatable')}}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'number', name: 'number' },
            { data: 'customer.title', name: 'customer' },
        ]
    });
});
```

And this Laravel method:

```
public function datatable()
{
    $drawings = Drawing::select(array('drawings.id','drawings.number'));

    return Datatables::of(Drawing::with('customer')->select('*'))->make(true);
}
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. How do I make datatable search window to work with `$customer->title`?
2. How do I display drawing number and customer title as link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    public function datatable()
    {

        //reference customer table
        $drawings = DB::table('customers')
            // join it with drawing table
            ->join('drawings', 'drawings.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
            //select columns for new virtual table. ID columns must be renamed, because they have the same title
            ->select(['drawings.id AS drawing_id', 'drawings.number', 'customers.title', 'customers.id AS customer_id']);

        // feed new virtual table to datatables and let it preform rest of the query (like, limit, skip, order etc.)
        return Datatables::of($drawings)
            ->editColumn('title', function($drawings) {
                return '<a href="'.route('customers.show', $drawings->customer_id).'">' . $drawings->title . '</a>';
            })  
            ->editColumn('number', function($drawings) {
                return '<a href="'.route('drawings.show', $drawings->drawing_id).'">' . $drawings->number . '</a>';
            })  
            ->make(true);
    }
```

Spent many hours trying to figure it out, hope it saves someone time.
http://datatables.yajrabox.com/fluent/joins

Comment: THAX ALOT, This helped me `select(['drawings.id AS drawing_id',......., 'customers.id AS customer_id']);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about your first question. Datatables search window will search all the content. Do you want to make it specific to just 1 column?

To answer your second question, you can edit the column output. Try this

```
$drawings = Drawing::select(array('drawings.id','drawings.number'));

return Datatables::of(Drawing::with('customer')->select('*'))
        ->editColumn('customer', function($drawings) {
            return '<a href="#">' . $drawings->customer . '</a>';
        })              
        ->make(true);
```

**Edit**

To achieve the search that you want, You'll want to do something like this:

```
public function datatable(Request $request)
{
    $drawings = Drawing::select(array('drawings.id','drawings.number'));

    return Datatables::of(Drawing::with('customer')->select('*'))
            ->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
                if ($request->has('name')) {
                    $query->where('customer.customer_name', 'like', "%{$request->get('name')}%");
                }
            })
            ->editColumn('customer', function($drawings) {
                return '<a href="#">' . $drawings->customer->customer_name . '</a>';
            })              
            ->make(true);
}
```

Then, in your JS

```
$(function () {
    $('#drawing-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '{{route('drawings.datatable')}}',
            data: function (d) {
                d.name = $('input[name=name]').val();
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'number', name: 'number' },
            { data: 'customer.title', name: 'customer' },
        ]
    });
});
```

This is untested, but should achieve what you want.

Comment: It wont search customer by name, because drawing table has customer_id column, but customer's title is in customer table

Comment: Okay, I've updated my post. If you have a relational model with the customer database, where you can find the customers name, then this will work. Just update the values, as I've guessed them; "customer_name", for example. The Laravel datatables package has a filter method, to add your own filters.

Comment: So there's no way to use regular search field, as this will keep resulting in `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer' in 'where clause' `? sad

Comment: You can change the name of the input in the JS. You could even do "type=search" which will target the built in search. That filter is only extending the default functionality. The unknown column error is because I don't know your column names. You'll need to change them, I was only guessing.

Comment: But if I use search for both - find drawings and filter out customer titles, doesn't it mean that `DataTable` will find all drawings `like` `'%'.$term.'%'` and then filter out results where `customer.title` also matches `'%'.$term.'%'`... leading to no results?

Comment: found the solution `$drawings = DB::table('customers')->join('drawings', 'drawings.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
            ->select(['drawings.id AS drawing_id', 'drawings.number', 'customers.title', 'customers.id AS customer_id']);` I'll post the full answer tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

you may also use elequent relationships with yajra here is the example code.

```
$sub_sectors = Sector::where('parent_id', '>', 0)->with('parent')->latest()->get();
$sub_sectors->each(function($sub_sectors){
    $sub_sectors->sector = $sub_sectors->parent->title['en'];
});
```

in this example you can get sector against sub sector with each method you can get sector name and now you can display sector in your yajra table