# Sorting by eloquent relationship in Laravel using DataTables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, datatables

I'm trying to use [DataTables](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/6.0) to display list of Application model.
Application model has operations:

```
public function operations(){
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Operation', 'application_id', 'id');
}
```

Operations model has state:

```
public function state(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\State', 'status_id', 'id');
}
```

and operation author (user):

```
public function user(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

To enable datatable i'm using this code:

```
                        $(function() {
                        $('#applications-table').DataTable({
                            language: {
                                "url": "/js/Polish.json"
                            },
                            processing: true,
                            serverSide: true,
                            ajax: '{!! route('applications.data') !!}',
                            columns: [
                                { data: 'number', name: 'number', className: "vertical_middle", searchable: true},
                                { data: 'operations.0.correspondence', name: 'operations.correspondence', className: "vertical_middle", orderable: false, searchable: false},
                                { data: 'operations.0.comment', name: 'operations.comment', className: "vertical_middle", orderable: false, searchable: true},
                                { data: 'operations.0.prognosed', name: 'operations.prognosed', className: "vertical_middle", searchable: false},
                                { data: 'operations.0.state.name', name: 'operations.state.name', className: "vertical_middle", searchable: false},
                                { data: 'operations.0.created_at', name: 'operations.created_at', className: "vertical_middle", type: "date", searchable: true},

                            ]
                        });

                    });
```

ApplicationController is serving data using this code

```
        $model = Application::with(array(
        'operations' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderByDesc('operations.created_at')->with('state')->with('user');
        }
    ));

    return Datatables::of($model)->make(true);
```

And finally a problem - table is rendering properly, but when I try to sort by another column than the first one I receive warning:

> DataTables warning: table id=applications-table - Requested unknown parameter 'operations.0.correspondence' for row 0.

Honestly, I have no idea how to make it work. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the results of the query, please? Because you should know that a DataTable expects you to write the exact column name as the query is returning.

Comment: @L.Flor Sure, here is the result of the query after click to sort another column. https://pastebin.com/X5PD0Kfd Anyway, it should return only 3 applications, but it returns 6 rows of data...

Comment: If you want to use `DataTables` I suggest you not to use relationships. It's better to use `DB::select` and then `join` it's better. But also, why are you using the `0` there?

Comment: To get first element of operations array. I've tried to make ->limit(1) or ->first() but it wasn't working... Something is definitely broken with creating this Eloquent model (probably my code) :)

Comment: Look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33163415/6459968 It's much better to use `DB::select` when using DataTables instead of an eloquent relationship.

Comment: I'll try to prepare this again using DB::table and this example [link](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/fluent/joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using **DB::table**

```
    $applications = DB::table('applications as a')
    ->join('operations as o', function($join){
        $join->on('o.application_id', '=', 'a.id')
            ->on('o.id', '=', DB::raw("(SELECT max(id) from operations WHERE operations.application_id = a.id)"));
    })
    ->join('users as u', 'o.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
    ->join('states as s', 'o.status_id', '=', 's.id')
    ->select(['a.id as a_id','a.number','o.*', 'u.name as u_name', 'u.surname as u_surname', 's.name as s_name']);

return Datatables::of($applications)->make(true);
```